# `Unexpected token < in JSON` error when passing PHP array to JSON

Tags: wordpress-rest-api

If anybody can point me in the right direction on this one, I will be eternally grateful!

I’m playing around with the WordPress `register_rest_field()` function (for the first time) to add a custom field to an existing endpoint in the Rest API.

Here is the snippet where I’ve registered my field:

```
register_rest_field(
    'country',
    'featured_post',
    array(
        'get_callback' => 'dd_return_featured_sound'
    )
);
```

And here is the callback function:

```
function dd_return_featured_sound( $object, $field_name, $request ) {

    $posts = get_field( 'featured_sound', $object['taxonomy'] . '_' . $object['id'] );
    $post  = $posts[0]; // $posts is an array, but there is only 1 featured post

    return array(
        'link'  => get_the_permalink( $post ),
        'title' => get_the_title( $post ),
        'terms' => get_the_terms( $post, $object['taxonomy'] ),
        'image' => get_the_post_thumbnail( $post )
    );

}
```

The problem is that I keep getting the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Here’s the relevant snippet of the js:

```
if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {

    const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

    // if there are terms to show
    if (data.length) {

        data.forEach(term => {

            console.log(term);

        });

    }

}
```

I’ve been trying to work this one out for the a couple of hours now and I’m close to tearing my hair out (I have a healthy head of hair and would very much like to keep it that way).

If anybody can help at all, like I said before, I'd be eternally grateful!

Comment: What does the response look like in the network tab in your browser's developer tools? You probably do have access to the information you need to debug this, you just don't know where to look yet. (hint: Javascript is trying to parse json, but the _very first character_ it's seeing in the response is a `<`. Probably because the response is `<html> ...`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I’m aware that first character in the response is a `<`, but what I’m saying is that I don’t understand why, considering that all I’m attempting to return is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Literally banging my head against the desk in disbelief at the fact that I didn’t realise this right away…

It transpires that the `featured_sound` field is in fact *not* mandatory, so naturally everything broke in the callback function when trying to get `[0]` of a non-existent array.